# Selecting a row in TStringGrid from click on any cell within that row.

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I have a TStringGrid object on a form which has 1 FixedCol and 1 FixedRow. I want to be able to select an entire row on the object when the user clicks on any cell within that row. This selection must also be visible to the user (I want the row to change colour).

EDIT: Have put goRowSelect in options on the object. Is there now a way to select the row on the click of one of the cells in the fixed column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable the option `goFixedColClick` of the string grid you can then use the `OnFixedCellClick` event to determine which row to select. You can then set `StringGrid1.Selection := TGridRect(Rect(0, Row, n, Row));` where Row is the row clicked and n is the width of your StringGrid.

Comment: Really sorry for my ignorance here... But how would I go about selecting the Row? I understand that I will need to use the ARow and ACol variables declared in the Sender section of the procedure but other than that, am pretty lost.

Comment: @Seryth I've updated my answer to include details on how to select a row in code.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure that the user clicked on a non-fixed row before changing the selection.

Answer (score 7):

In order highlight entire row when ever the user clicks on any cell in that row, set the following StringGrid properties.

In design time: Go to options property and check the following sub-properties.

```
goEditing := TRUE;
goRowSelect := TRUE;
```

To achieve this at run time,

```
StringGrid1.Options := StringGrid1.Options + [goEditing];
StringGrid1.Options := StringGrid1.Options + [goRowSelect];
```